# OPOS image capture with Symbol Digital Image Scanner

Tags: barcode-scanner, image-scanner, opos

Our application presently uses the Motorola/Symbol DS6707 Digital Image Scanner for both image capture and barcode scanning.  We communicate with the scanner via the Moto SNAPI driver.  Since this is specific to the Motorola/Symbol scanner, I am considering a rewrite using a more generic interface, such as OPOS.  This is in a C/C++ application.

We also have a Honeywell imaging scanner in house that we are testing with.  This model (Xenon 1900) also an supports both imaging and the barcode scanning.

Both scanners have OPOS drivers for support under the 'scanner' (bar code reader) device class.  Neither has support as an 'imaging scanner'.  However, the Honeywell supports imaging through the scanner driver using DirectIO, which is documented in their SDK's.

Does anyone know if the Motorola OPOS driver supports imaging, and if so, what the DirectIO commands would be?  I cannot find any SDK or other documentation for the Motorola/Symbol OPOS support.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Documentation is impossible to find via the Symbol/Motorola websites directly.  I did end up finding the *MOTOROLA SCANNER OPOS DRIVER DEVELOPER’S GUIDE* after MANY creative google searches on the [Symbol website](https://docs.symbol.com/manuals/14978301a.pdf?userId=37) and discovered on page 3-5 that DirectIO is "Not supported. Always returns OPOS_E_ILLEGAL".

Guess we will need to find another solution.

Answer (score 3):

we are also working on a solution to this using UPOS to create a standard interface for ImageScanner device using Honeywell Xenon 1900 or 4600.

I have been in touch with the manufacturer.  They arent a lot of help so far.

The approach we are taking is using direct i/o to initalize the image scanner and to pull down the image via USB HID interface.  We already have a connection to the device established via USB HID interface (plug and play).

I think it will be possible to do this but not simple.

If you want to collaberate on this let me know.
devbrilliance@live.com

Comment: The Honeywell driver does not present itself as an image scanner class as far as I recall.  It looks like it presents itself as a scanner, but supports the image capture via direct IO.  Their example OPOS app demonstrates theis feature, but from my experience the image quality is lacking.

Comment: You are correct.  The image scanner class is not supported by Honeywell (or any other scanner manufacturer).  This is the purpose of Direct i/o anyway, which is to enable features not directly supported by the service object.      I hope it is possible to modify the service object itself to do some of this work directly and this is the task we are currently reviewing.

Comment: The Universal POS spec does call for an ImageScanner class, which may or may not interact with the scanner class.  Devices such as we are discussing should properly be an ImageScanner, as they support both image and barcode capture.  Check out the sequence diagrams for ImageScanners (pg 667-670 of the Universal POS 1.13 spec).  Seems entirely appropriate for this class of device.

Comment: At this point, our intention is to use the Honeywell drivers as-is, because they function properly in both 32 and 64 bit OS's.  We will use the Scanner class with DirectIO.  Since the Motorola/Symbol drivers do not work 64 bit at all, and don't support image capture even if they did, we are currently investigating writing our own OPOS controls using the same DirectIO commands as the HW for consistency.

Comment: Hi Tevo.  We believe we will have this solved and have functional ImageScanner driver in the next 30 days.  Due to costs we have incurred we will likely make available the driver for sale under license to recoup our costs.

Comment: Project has been completed  http://goldcirclesystems.com/Products/ImageScannerSOAK.aspx