# capturing images with datalogic heron HD3430 scanner using POS .Net

Tags: c#, .net, opos, pos

I've been working recently on developing system uses Barcode reader device with OPOS driver and i am stuck at this point.

i tried the demo provided with the driver and the only way i figured out to use barcode as reader only (not capturing image).

and after reading the documentation for POS .Net 1.14 i found a class named "ImageScanner", so i thought this could help me to find a solution for the problem but unfortunately i didn't find any example or tutorial to use aforementioned class and all i found was the same thing in the demo ("Scanner" class) and it only returns the barcode data as text (after decoding).
appreciating any useful help or examples.

Note: i found a book named professional's guide to pos for .net but it's not free so i couldn't  read it.

Comment: Hi Mazen and welcome to stackoverflow. As the question stands, it is rather likely to get closed (and, what's worse, rather unlikely to get any helpful answers). Please take a minute to look at [how to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so the community can actually help you.

Comment: You should ask this subject to [DataLogic technical support](http://www.datalogic.com/eng/products/healthcare-retail/hand-held-scanners/heron-hd3430-pd-694.html#support).

Comment: @kunif thank you for your advise. I don't think DataLogic support people could help, as long as it's related to POSfor.Net SDK noting i am asking for help to use the "ImageScanner" class.

Answer (score 1):

I am not registered as developer on DataLogic's site, so I can not get documents or software, but there may be some information in them.

By the way, In the past there was a similar question with another company's scanner, it itself has not been solved.
[OPOS image capture with Symbol Digital Image Scanner](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8072229/9014308)

In the second answer above, as the old POS for.NET 1.12, it seems that he created a development kit for the ImageScanner service object.
[IMAGESCANNER SERVICE OBJECT AUTOMATION KIT](http://goldcirclesystems.com/Products/ImageScannerSOAK.aspx)

It seems that site and software updates are not being done, but if you contact here, there may be progress in your wishes.

---

### In Addition:

Perhaps Heron HD 3430 is not considered to have the function of notifying image data.

I found the manuals of Heron HD 3430 and Magellan 3200 VSi below, but Magellan has a description of the interface to get the image, but Heron does not have such a description.

[Heron™ HD3430 - bsr.at](https://www.bsr.at/mediafiles/Handbuch/Datalogic/Big_Product_Reference_Guide_Heron_HD3430_EN.pdf)
[Magellan 3200 Product Reference Guide - barcodescanner.de](https://www.barcodescanner.de/media/pdf/specials/Magellan%203200VSi.pdf)

Comment: i already checked the previous question and its answers and i tried to deal with my barcode as scanner class and DirectI/O to switch between device modes in order to take images with data but these approach costs me time when running the application in each switch (my application will take image,image with decode, and decoded data) ..thanks and I wish that i can up vote your answer because reading the comments was useful for me after i had some understanding that i was missing when i started with the device for the first time.

Comment: thank you for the update. after searching i found this device is not considered as ImageScanner .. just scanner actually and the only way to capture images using it is to switch between its modes (image now, image on trigger, .. , etc.) and that was the only way.